# How to reset d3 graph to its original place?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6hdp2gkz/, where there are 3 draggable circles. At the first load, I am printing the original X position in the console. I want to drag the circles and when I press the 'Click me' button to be able to reset the three circles to their original position(as the position they were placed at the first time the page was loaded).
How can I achieve this?

This is the circle variable, which also gets the initial positions of the circles:

```
var circles = d3.select("svg")
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "circles")
    .selectAll("circle")
        .data(circle_data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {console.log("Initial X position is "+d.x);return(d.x)})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return(d.y)})
        .attr("r", radius)
        .attr("fill", "orange");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches here, the simplest one being just dropping the datum change inside the drag handler and using the bound data to reposition the circles:

```
function reset(source) {
  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {console.log("Initial X position is "+d.x);return(d.x)})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return(d.y)})
}
```

Here is your code with that change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<button type="button" class="btn options-bar-btn" onclick="onResetGraphBtnClick()" tooltip="Reset Graph" placement="bottom">CLick me
</button>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");


  //create some circles at random points on the screen

  //create 50 circles of radius 20
  //specify centre points randomly through the map function 
  radius = 20;
  var circle_data = d3.range(3).map(function() {
    return {
      x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - radius * 2) + radius),
      y: Math.round(Math.random() * (height - radius * 2) + radius)
    };
  });

  //add svg circles 
  var circles = d3.select("svg")
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "circles")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(circle_data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      console.log("Initial X position is " + d.x);
      return (d.x)
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return (d.y)
    })
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("fill", "orange");



  var drag_handler = d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .attr("cx", d3.event.x)
        .attr("cy", d3.event.y);
    });

  //apply the drag_handler to our circles 
  drag_handler(circles);

  function reset(source) {
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        console.log("Initial X position is " + d.x);
        return (d.x)
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return (d.y)
      })
  }

  function onResetGraphBtnClick() {
    reset(svg);
    console.log("CLICKED" + drag_handler);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: But how does the position of x and y from the reset method get the initial one and not the dragged position?

Comment: Because that's the bound datum, which was not changed.

Comment: I am using this method in an angular application and when i click the reset button, the circles aren't taken to their original position, that's why i am asking :)

Comment: or is it possible to create a behavior as in the refresh of the browser? just so that the circles will go back to their original place. Do you know how can I achieve this? @Gerardo Furtado

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! But is there any other solution, to reset the position based on a refresh behavior but only for the circles, not the browser page? Still based on the code I shared